# Dynamically Rendering Custom Component in SvelteKit

Tags: sveltekit

I've got some text that I want to inject tooltip info into, I'm currently considering using [this plugin](https://github.com/svelte-plugins/tooltips), however I can't seem to figure out how to render HTML that includes custom components or attributes like `use:tooltip`, using `@html` simply renders the content of the component as plain HTML, [svelte:element](https://svelte.dev/docs/special-elements#svelte-element) seems to only be able to dynamically change the type of an element.

Ideally I'd save the HTML to be rendered in a database and simply fetch and display, however if the only option is to do it in runtime that'd have to do.